# Is it possible to keep training the same Azure Translate Custom Model with additional data sets?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I just finished training a Custom Azure Translate Model with a set of 10.000 sentences. I now have the options to review the result and test the data. While I already get a good result score I would like to continue training the same model with additional data sets before publishing. I cant find any information regarding this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/v2-preview/how-to/train-custom-model).
The only remotely close option I can see is to duplicate the first model and add the new data sets but this would create a new model and not advance the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Once the project is created, we can train with different models on different datasets. Once the dataset is uploaded and the model was trained, we cannot modify the content of the dataset or upgrade it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/quickstart-build-deploy-custom-model

The above document can help you.